# event based trigger hangs the process

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, custom-options

I created a event based trigger for customer registration .

```
 <customer_register_success>
     <observers>
         <Magestore_Sociallogin_observer>
             <type>singleton</type>
             <class>sociallogin/observer</class>
             <method>customerRegisterSuccess</method>
         </Magestore_Sociallogin_observer>
     </observers>
 </customer_register_success>
```

In Observer.php

```
public function customerRegisterSuccess($observer)
{                
    $email = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer()->getEmail();
    echo "Its working fine";

}
```

Background customer registration process is done successfully but on fronted no message shown .

If i remove echo it works fine.

[image: ajax loader]

How to echo these values just to check weather i am getting or not in my function.

```
   $customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();

            $email = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer()->getEmail();
            $contact = $customer->getAddressesCollection()->getFirstitem()->getTelephone();
```

**Update**

Extension stop working if there is any error in Observer.php , but my concern at this point is how to know where I am wrong, as it doesn't throw any error. Just hangs the functionality.

Comment: comment observer  code in config.xml. and try to regsiter customer

Comment: If I comment then everything works.